# Gradle fails when I try to run my android app, cause is blank

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

The gradle console says that it has an unexpected top level exception while parsing some of my classes. I made a library and imported it into my android project in Android Studio. I know Android studio is working correctly because a basic "hello world" app runs fine. When I try to add functionality from the imported jar library, gradle has problems. An error message pops up saying the build failed, with no cause listed. The gradle console lists a bunch of errors which I've pasted below.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/aptosstbbq/bbqapp/util/Utils.class

1 error; aborting
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/aptosstbbq/bbqapp/web/WebIn.class

1 error; aborting

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Aaron\AndroidStudioProjects\AptosStBBQ\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\bbqClasses-741f4ab1e806e3a2d760c8f3cc4058d1ea8bd147.jar C:\Users\Aaron\AndroidStudioProjects\AptosStBBQ\app\libs\bbqClasses.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    ...while parsing com/aptosstbbq/bbqapp/util/Utils.class

    1 error; aborting


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.852 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your platform-tool and open terminal there and simply give permission to all of them

```
sudo chmod 777 *
```

And do the same to the tools folder

It worked for me.